# Selenium to click a dynamic link

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

I am automating a process using selenium. But I am stuck with something. I have to click a link using selenium. This link is a anchor tag and has no id. The link (which will be specified in the href attribute) will be generated dynamically. It's the name of the document and will be something like `<a href="www..*&filename=readme123_55.txt" />`. For another page it will be `<a href="www..*&filename=readme567_89.txt" />`.

Now, to simulate the click of this link, is there any way to click it? How to get the dynamically generated link? I am using Java code for selenium.

Comment: Are the links at predictable locations in the DOM? If so, just access them by index in your locator like this: `css=div.mylinks a:nth-child(2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If some part of id is static then you can use :contains for locate that link

**selenium.click("//a[contains(@href,'*some static content of that id*')]")**